# Android bounce animation with two scale

Tags: android, android-animation

I want 1st my layout zoom up, 2nd it should zoom out with bounce. But this code doesn't work correctly.

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:ordering="sequentially" >
<set>
    <scale
        android:duration="400"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="1.2"
        android:toYScale="1.2" />
</set>

<set android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator" >
    <scale
        android:duration="800"
        android:fromXScale="1.2"
        android:fromYScale="1.2"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0" />
</set></set>
```

Comment: did you resolve this taks with help only xml?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know much about object animator but i did scaling with property animation several times and it worked just fine! here is the code

```
    AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet(); //this is your animation set. 
    //add as many Value animator to it as you like

    ValueAnimator scaleUp = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(1,(float)1.2);
    scaleUp.setDuration(800);
    scaleUp.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator()); //remove this if you prefer default interpolator
    scaleUp.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            Float newValue = (Float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
            yourView.setScaleY(newValue);
            yourView.setScaleX(newValue);
        }
    });

    ValueAnimator scaleDown = ValueAnimator.ofFloat((float)1.2,1);
    scaleDown.setDuration(800);
    scaleDown.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
    scaleDown.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            Float newValue = (Float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
            yourView.setScaleY(newValue);
            yourView.setScaleX(newValue);
        }
    });


    set.play(saceleUp);
    set.play(scaleDown).after(scaleUP);
    set.start();
```

Comment: What about double scale?)

Comment: Too much code, guess) This task should be solved by animation xml

Comment: You may prefer doing this with xml but i think this is better for two reasons. 1)You write too many lines of code but your code is not complex! In fact if you learn basic of value animator (takes less than 15 minutes) you get very comfortable with it! 2) it gives you full control over animation, it really becomes handy when animations are complex. Anyway it's my opinion if you like xml go for it.